# Is there a point in using an object in an event listener?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have seen people using an object instead of a function in `addEventListener(eventName, objInsteadOfFunction)`. Why would that be? It only seems to introduce the need for state.

```
const TbodyApp = {
    handleEvent: handleTbodyClick,
    curElementSelectionState,
    handleTrClick: function init() {
        return handleTrClick.bind(this,
            getRenderDecisions, getNewState, renderChangesBound);
    },
    isTargetValidForTrClickHandler,
    isTrClickHandlerToBeActivated
};
TbodyApp.handleTrClick = TbodyApp.handleTrClick();
```

I tried to use an object and some of the functions started having fewer parameters and instead started to use this. On top of that, I had to do gymnastics as in the code above in order to initialize the object.

```
function handleTbodyClick(evt) {
    const target = evt.target;

    if (this.isTargetValidForTrClickHandler(target)) {
        this.isTrClickHandlerToBeActivated(evt, target);
    }
}
```

The this-es in this function were parameters and are now in the object. It only makes testing more difficult and the code more confusing. Is there a point in using an object instead of a function in an event listener?

Comment: According to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) on the second argument to `.addEventListener()`,  "*This must be an object implementing the EventListener interface, or a JavaScript function.*" So, using an object does give you state as well as behavior, but you can't just pass any old object.

Comment: @Scott Marcus, Doesn't the function give me behavior, too? I understand the object needs to implement the EventListener interface, but does it give me any use or is it just an option?

Comment: Yes, the function is the behavior. The object is state and behavior.

Comment: Okay, thank you. So is it a good practice to use an object. Isn't state usually a bad idea?

Comment: In my experience, you'll see function references much more often than objects (the ability to pass an object only got added to the API in the last several years). There is no right or wrong here. You have the choice so that you can build what fits your needs.